# htmlspecialchars() vs htmlpurifier library

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, htmlpurifier

What are the differences between the built-in php method htmlspecialchars() and htmlpurifier library?

Comment: @Downvoter Sir/Madam, May I please ask what wrong did I do. So that I can rectify my mistake...

Comment: There's really not much sense fretting over individual downvotes. That said, they may have been frustrated by the fact that you didn't do much digging into the documentation of the two functions - the differences are pretty clear if you read more than a minute or two.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for informing the reason behind the downvote. Actually, I did search for more than 2 hours before posting this question. My experience is far less than anyone else in this community. So the things that you guys can make out just by looking at it for a "minute or two", it requires me an entire day. Even then also I fail to find something suitable. Sorry for my ignorance and bad English. It is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to stop any HTML from being used, use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`.

HTML Purifier is intended to let you allow *some* HTML, with quite a few options - for example, you can allow video embeds *only* from YouTube, or allow only *certain* CSS classes on *certain* HTML tags. Handy if you're building a CMS or something where you want to allow people to use HTML but not permit malicious use.

It can also make HTML fixes, like adding default `alt` tags to images, cleanup of invalid or unnecessary code, etc.

Peruse [the available configuration options](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html) for an idea of what's possible.

Comment: You forgot to mention, `htmlspecialchars` converts things like `>` and `<` to `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: @TyQ. So does HTML Purifier, if you configure it to.